# Save file Python - IOError Permission Denied

Tags: javascript, python, image, http, chmod

I am making a post request to a python script and then I want to save an image file to the server, in the html folder here is what I am doing

```
fh = open("/var/www/html/images/logo.png", "wb")
fh.write(image_data.decode('base64'))
fh.close()
```

but then I get this error, `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:` I have found out that it means this file doest have permission to save the image, and I could get around it by doing chmod to `777` but that is dangerous and bad, so how else can I save the file but not let the file be edited by anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could either change the permissions or run the script as a user with the correct permissions. I don't see many other options. You could have your script edit the permissions, write, and then change the permissions back although it would still be editable for a moment, and it just seems like a bad idea. The script could fail for some reason and leave the permissions allowing anyone to edit. Edit: If you can change the permission you should be able to write, making my last idea pointless.

Comment: thanks for reply, I am calling script with a post request from some javascript so how can I set the user?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with javascript. I added a javascript tag. Hopefully someone will come along to help

Answer (score 0):

It may appear a bit convoluted but I suggest that you might want to investigate the /etc/sudoers file.
For your purposes, you would create the file somewhere that you do have permissions like /tmp and then `move` it to `/var/www/html/images/` using a script that is named as a `sudoers` `Cmnd_Alias`.
You still need to envoke the `Cmnd_Alias` script with `sudo` but if you have declared it with `NOPASSWD` then it should just function without asking for the `sudo` password.

Always access the `/etc/sudoesrs` file using `visudo`
an example of the entries in that file:

```
# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias WEB  = /home/test.s
```

and then later in the file:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
rolf    ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:WEB
```

with this, the `/home/test.sh` will perform whatever task the user `rolf` sets it, such as moving a file from `/tmp` to `/var/www/html/images/` when the command line, `sudo /home/test.sh` is issued, without asking for the password.